# react app: issue with having multiple ag-grids within tabs

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a react app which uses multiple ag-grids, some within tabs.

[As per this issue raised for ag-grid,](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1293) when you have multiple ag-grids, some hidden within tabs, you can get warnings on console relating to zero width columns:

`ag-Grid: tried to call sizeColumnsToFit() but the grid is coming back with zero width, maybe the grid is not visible yet on the screen?`

Does anyone have any advice on how to resolve this? The original poster simply switched to having one grid which I cannot do

As far as I'm aware, I can run the app just fine even with the warning, but I was hoping to try and fix it in case it produces unexpected issues in the future

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue but turned out to be a bug where I was accidentally setting gridApi to undefined temporarily while switching grid data source.